# c program for the reverse the digits

Tags: c, reverse

I am looking for the `C` program for reverse the digits like below:

If i enter:

> 123456

Then the result would be:

> 654321

Please help me.

Comment: Please learn how to answer questions intelligently.

Comment: Appears like a famous 'C' interview question :-)

Comment: Are you sitting in an interview right now? Then we'd better hurry to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `% 10` to get the last digit. Output it. Divide the number by 10 to get all but the last digit. Use `% 10` to get the last digit of that. And so on, until the number becomes 0.

Comment: as in `char buf[12]; snprintf(buf, 16, "% 10d", n);  for ( size_t i = 10; i --> 0 && buf[i] > 42; ) printf("%c", buf[i]);`

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: Cute and confusing what you did there.  One thinks at first *wait, there's no "goes to" operator in C*.

Comment: i want the complete no this will generate the no 12345
as

5
4
3
2
1
but i want 54321
compete

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple solution to this complex problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch != '\n') {
        main();
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
}
```

---

A new version that outputs the newline:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void newline(void)
{
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int ch;
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch != '\n') {
        main();
        printf("%c", ch);
    } else {
        atexit(newline);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume I was down voted because I didn't print the trailing newline? It was not a requirement. ;-)

Comment: But why not make it also print the newline? I'll +1 you if you do :P.

Comment: Just a note: calling `main` recursively is not allowed in C++.

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++.

Comment: @Richard: Printing the final newline may be required by your C implementation. I don't have the standard but draft n1256 (C99 + TC1 + TC2) 7.19.2p2 says in part "Whether the
last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined."

Comment: @Philip: That's interesting. I'd be pretty surprised if the standard didn't require that buffered output be flushed on program termination.

Comment: @Richard: If your implementation requires something of your program, and your program doesn't do it, then the behaviour is undefined, and so no, the standard doesn't require anything. I don't know of any systems which actually require the newline, but your program isn't strictly conforming unless it provides it. (Clearly, this is the most important criticism there is of your program :-)

Comment: @Philip: See 7.20.4.3: The standard does require that streams be flushed. 7.19.2p2 just says it implementation defined whether the lack of trailing newline has any consequences. Not undefined, just implementation defined.

Comment: @Richard I think we're dangerously close to angels-on-pinheads here :)

Answer (score 7):

If your professor is grading you on performance, then try [ggf31416's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433211/quickest-method-to-reverse-in-string-in-c-net/433257#433257) to this problem in another question:

```
int FastReverse(int num) {
    int res = 0;
    int q = (int)((214748365L * num) >> 31);
    int rm = num - 10 * q;
    num = q;
    if (rm == 0) return -1;
    res = res * 10 + rm;
    while (num > 0) {
       q = (int)((214748365L * num) >> 31);
       rm = num - 10 * q;
       num = q;
       res = res * 10 + rm;
    }
    return res;
}
```

#### Optimization<sup><sup>®</sup></sup>

<sup>When it absolutely, positively has to be done this nanosecond.</sup>

Comment: This hurts my eyes. Also upvote for optimizing something that hardly takes anytime on it's own.

Comment: If the input is 120, what is the expected output? I think 021 or 21. Same for 1200. Is this algorithm producing correct results when the the input has trailing 0's?

Comment: @ArunSaha:  Given the application for the original algorithm, it does a fast exit when given a number with a trailing zero.  And given that the expected output for an input with a trailing zero is not well defined here, I'd say that's still reasonable behavior.  To remove this behavior, one must simply comment out the line `if (rm == 0) return -1;`.  In this case, given 1200, it would return 21.  Formatting with leading zeros would be the responsibility of a higher-order function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possibility. It is non-recursive, and perhaps a little less code. There is an example in the code comments to explain the logic.

```
/*
    Example: input = 12345

    The following table shows the value of input and x
    at the end of iteration i (not in code) of while-loop.
    ----------------------
    i   |   input  |    x
    ----------------------
    0       12345       0
    1        1234       5
    2         123      54
    3          12     543
    4           1    5432
    5           0   54321
    ----------------------
*/
uint32_t
reverseIntegerDigits( uint32_t input )
{
    uint32_t x = 0;

    while( input )
    {
        x = 10 * x + ( input % 10 );
        input = input / 10;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the number in a char array `A` with `scanf("%s", A)` or, better, with [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) and output the char array reversed by outputting each character starting from `strlen(A) - 1` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

strrev function reverses the string. If performance is not a problem then for instance you can do itoa, then strrev, then atoi.
But the task is very simple even without strrev.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, strrev is not a standard function, and may not be available on all compilers.

Comment: Yes, sure. In such case own implementation of strrev will help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a very old thread. But I referred the solutions here and had to cook up my own solution after testing the different programs available as solution on this website. I realized that treating the number as int will not yield necessary reversing of digit if the number ends with zero(s). So I decided to treat the number as a string and then reverse the digits. This way, I get exact reverse of the digit from a string standpoint and not a mathematical one that discards zeros at the beginning of a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{

    char num[20];
    int x=0,slen;

    printf("Enter the number you want to reverse :");
    scanf("%s",num);
    slen=strlen(num);


    char *pointertoarray = &num[slen];

    for (x=slen;x>=0; x--){ printf("%c",*pointertoarray); pointertoarray--; }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. count the number of digits in number and store in count variable
2. extract individual digits in variable
3. use the power function.

   ```
   while(count>=1)
   {
     var = num % 10;
     sum = sum + var * pow(10, count - 1);
     num =num / 10;
     count--;
   }
   ```