# Can't put class with main function?

Tags: c++, function, class, header, member

Something I am working on is making a code that focuses on making a class that reverses an order of numbers. This will then get put into the main code that will eliminate any trailing zeroes. I can't seem to wrap my head around how classes work and where I am going wrong. Here is my code:

Numbers.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Numbers
{
public:
int digit
private:
void Numbers::reverse();
};
```

Numbers.cpp

```
#include "Numbers.h
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Numbers::reverse(){
int n, reversedNumber = 0, remainder;

cout << "Enter the number you would like to manipulate!   " << endl;
cin >> n;

while (n !=0)
{
remainder = n % 10;
reversedNumber = reversed Number * 10 + remainder;
n /= 10;
}
//return *this;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "Numbers.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Numbers.reverse;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to make the reverse function in my Numbers.cpp work in the main function. I am new to C++ and am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: BTW, syntax for calling a function or method is to use `()` at the end of the name, as in `Numbers.reverse()`. *(This should be `Numbers::reverse()`, since `Numbers` is a type and not an instance of a type.)*

Comment: You are not making the function call. Use `Numbers.reverse();`.

Comment: you create a private function, it should be static public to access it this way

Comment: `Numbers.reverse()` won't work, as `reverse` is a member function and it is `private`. You need to pick up a good C++ book

Comment: Also, either create an instance of `Numbers` or declare the `reverse` function as static.

Comment: Your private and public parts are backwards.  The variable should be private and the function public

Comment: You don't need to prefix methods with their class names inside the declaration.  Example:  `public: reverse();` not `public: Numbers::reverse();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there are a lot of mistakes or learning errors in your code. Your header file should look something like:

```
#pragma once

class Numbers
{
public:
  Numbers();
  ~Numbers();

  int Reverse(int input);  // Function is 'public'.
};
```

Your CPP file will then be (parts taken from S.O. post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806167/reverse-the-position-of-integer-digits)):

```
#include "Numbers.h"

Numbers::Numbers()
{
}

Numbers::~Numbers()
{
}

// No need to store the value in 'digit' since this
// is just an algorithm which can return the result.
int Numbers::Reverse(int input)
{
  int ret = 0;

  while(input > 0)
  {
    ret = ret * 10 + (input % 10);
    input = input / 10;
  }

  return ret; // Return the reversed number and let the user decide what to do.
}
```

Then you can use your class as follows:

```
#include "Numbers.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num;

  cout << "Enter a number to reverse: ";
  cin >> num;

  Numbers numClass;

  cout << "Reversed number is: " << numClass.Reverse(num) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you call `numClass(2400)` it will return `42` and **not** return `0042`. Any trailing zeros will be removed.