# How do invert a number in C while still including zeroes?

Tags: c, int, reverse

I want to reverse an `int` so the order changes from "first to last" to "last to first" (eg; `123` becomes `321`, `100` becomes `001`, `0003` becomes `3000` etc..)

I have the following code, but based on the way it works any leading or trailing zeroes before or after the process are completely skipped. (`0003` becomes `3`)

```
int reverseNumber(int number);

main()
{
 int s = 123000000;
 printf("%d\n", reverseNumber(s));
}

int reverseNumber(int number) {
  int reversedNumber = 0, remainder;
  while(number != 0)
      {
          remainder = number%10;
          reversedNumber = reversedNumber*10 + remainder;
          number /= 10;
      }
  return reversedNumber;
}
```

How can I alter the code so it works without omitting zeroes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c program for the reverse the digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351251/c-program-for-the-reverse-the-digits)

Comment: You need another type than `int` to represent leading zeroes, the most obvious being `char *`.

Comment: I have attempted the answer to the linked question which is where I have derived my code from. I'd like to inverse a number while still keeping the zeroes.

Comment: @Sneftel, the question you link does not address leading zeroes.

Comment: What you want is impossible. A zero or any other number of zeros in front of a number do not change its value. 000001 is identically equal to 1.

Comment: @mouviciel Read dina's answer to the linked question.

Comment: You won't do it using `int` as the resulting data type. Leading zeros mean *nothing* to `int`.  S string of `char` on the other hand...

Answer (score 0):

Because leading zeroes have no value, you need to tell your function the number of digits, or the number of leading zeroes, the supplied values has.

The number of leading zeroes is easier:

```
unsigned int reverseNumber(unsigned int number, unsigned int leadingzeroes)
{
    unsigned int reversedNumber = 0;

    while (number) {
        reversednumber = 10*reversednumber + number%10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    while (leadingzeroes-->0) {
        reversednumber = 10*reversednumber;
    }

    return reversedNumber;
}
```